# Load video file dynamically with starting and ending points jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm displaying a full video on page load with option for user to select specific segments having starting and ending point. I need whenever user click on any specific segment video should start from that starting point and end at segment's ending point as shown in attached screenshot.

```
http://prntscr.com/f0xfav
```

jwplayer version: 5.10.2295

My code is as below:

```
jwplayer('viewer').setup({
    flashplayer: '<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jwplayer/player.swf',
    file: '<?php echo $generalInfo->resourceUrl; ?>',
    height: 400,
    width: 900
});

//below code work but I'm not sure if it's correct way to achieve this.
jwplayer().onPlay(function () {
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        jwplayer().seek(30);
    }, 500);
});

jwplayer().onTime(function () {
    if (jwplayer().getPosition() >= '60') {
        jwplayer().play(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest version of JWplayer which is version 7. The new version has improved support for html5 video and audio.

Comment: @NadirLatif it's also working in this version but i want to know is it correct way to achieve this functionality? I'm using jwplayer for the first time and don't know if it's good way. Thanks!